# .Net equivalent of Java 'Collections.disjoint()' method?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any [`Collections.disjoint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) (Java language) like API or library for .NET (C#)?

From the API description:

> disjoint returns true if the two specified collections have no
>   elements in common.

Comment: _Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: @SonerGönül: I don't think it's really asking for a tool recommendation in the normal way. Asking for a .NET equivalent of a specific method seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: I agree with Jon, the question is just asking for a common function, I do think the question should have included information about what `Disjoint` is though instead of a link (I don't like clicking on links)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for the LINQ [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method:

```
bool disjoint = !collection1.Intersect(collection2).Any();
```

Comment: Thank you.
I'm sure it works functionally.

But I'm afraid intersection is slower, when intersection size gets sometimes large.

In my test code (in Java) shows that [ListUtils.intersection](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/index.html) is about 60x slower than [Collections.disjoint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).
(8116ms and 125ms, respectively)

Comment: See how `var intersects = coll1.Any(coll2.Contains);` works for you.

Comment: @takagiko: You're making an assumption that `Enumerable.Intersect` works the same way as `ListUtils.Intersection` - I very much doubt that's the case. In particular, `Intersect` is lazy - it doesn't compute the intersection up front; instead, when asked for the first element it will create a `HashSet` from `collection2` and then stream `collection1` through that set. The fact that we're using `Any` means it can stop when it's found the first match.

Comment: @JonasElfström: That will be O(N * M) (assuming `coll2` isn't a set) instead of O(N + M).

Comment: You are right, that's a stupid idea. I forgot that .Intersect obviously returns a IEnumerable and that the .Any will return as soon as the first intersection is found.

Comment: You're right. `ListUtils.Intersection` does work eager. Now I understand that `collection1.Intersect(collection2).Any()` works the same-order-speed as `Collections.disjoint()`. Thank you again!